# PhoneGap project builds for different environments using XCode - Best practise

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap and Xcode/Mac world and developing an iOS app using PhoneGap and Xcode with build done on a local Mac machine. We need multiple builds for different environments like Dev, QA, Integration, Staging and Production. Once a dev build is done and ipa file is created for it to run as QA build, it needs only a single configuration change to set the environment. But unlike other applications, we cannot change the config value once the build is generated for an ipa file.

In this scenario, what will be the best way to create multiple build packages for each environment? 
All Dev, QA, Intg and prod apps should run on the same iPad too. 
Can we set the config file in the .plist file and read it using javascript using phonegap APIs?
Are there any build scripts available which will give 4 packages  for different environments ?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks.